# How to disable UITableViewCell selection one by one?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am creating a table view based iPhone application, Where i need to disable one by one entire table view cell.

The requirement is like -

Case-1 :-

Initially only first table cell row should be user interaction enable, rest should be disable. We can easily do this to make indexPath.row 0 enable in CellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Case-2 :-

If User will tap on First cell and when again he will come back then First cell will be disable and second cell should enable(rest table cell will be disable at this time after second cell).

Case-3 :-

Again if user will tap on second table cell and come back to this table then apart from Third cell, others should be disable and so on...

It means i need to disable one by one all the table cell in serial order.It is possible by setting index but it won't be the proper way to do this. So, can you please suggest me what condition i need to give for this ? Please suggest me for further proceeding.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just maintain an instance variable which holds the cell number that should be enabled.e.g. enabledCell.

Initialize enabledCell to 0. In didSelectRow increment enabledCell and reload the tableView. In cell for row at indexPath only enable the cell if the indexPath is same as the enabledCell value.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    // write code to dequeue or create new UITableViewCell here
    // then check if index is same as the cell that should be enabled
    if(index.Path.row == enabledCell)
       cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    else
       cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //Assuming you have number of rows stored in variable numberOfRows
     enabledCell++;
     if(enabledCell == numberOfRows)
       enabledCell = 0;
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: @KedarThanks for your idea but there is something wrong, it should be like if (indexPath.row == enabledCell) then cell.userInteractionEnabled = Yes; and else it will no user interaction. One upvote for your best suggestion...thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this (from now on, I'm a assuming a linear table view with `n` rows and only one section).

For example, you can add a `BOOL enabled` property to your cell model object. In your controller's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` check that property and do nothing if it's set to `NO`. If it's set to `YES` then navigate to the appropriate page and exchange the `enabled` property with the one at index position i + 1 (or position 0 if it's the last entry and you want to cycle).